# VBA: activating/selecting a worksheet/row/cell

Tags: vba, excel

Hello Stackoverflowers,

I'm trying to use a button, that first goes to another excel file in a specific directory. While performing something, I want to add a row in a sheet the excel file i'm running the button from.
To do that, i need to activate a certain row, or cell to use this

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
```

but it keeps telling me:

```
activate method of range class failed
```

my last trail was this:

```
Sheet1.Cells(2, 3).Activate
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this done? i think because i'm in another workbook or something

Thanks

Comment: Are you activating the workbook first?

Comment: Try Sheet1.Cells(2,3).EntireRow.Insert. Alternatively, try Application.GoTo Sheet1.Cells(2,3)

Comment: Ok, re-read, try @Barranka's suggestion first.

Comment: I couldn't activate the workbook, can please tell me how? i'll try the other solutions for the time being

Comment: that worked! i was using this also (old code i tried as well):     Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(2).Insert, didn't work too

Comment: dim openedWorkbook as WorkBook. set openedWorkbook = workbooks.open("path"). openedWorkbook.activate.

Comment: @mkingston I've used that to open another file. are you suggesting i do it to my original excel file to return to it?

Comment: @himura Just one thing: I think you should use `Cells(2,3).Select` instead of `Cells(2,3).Activate`

Comment: hmmmm, i'm no expert, but can you tell me why? so i can understand for later :)

Comment: @himura I was suggesting you use that code to open/activate your new workbook. You can use Workbooks("filename.xls").Activate to activate any already open workbook.

Comment: Why are you using activate in the first place?  You do realise that you don't actually need to select or activate neither the workbook or the cell, to insert cells, right?

Comment: + 1 @Reafidy for the only one who suggested not to use `.Activate` -@himura: Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select

Comment: @Reafidy yes I've realized that. The thing is that all examples i saw in the net to add rows uses activate or select... and since i'm still new to VBA, i couldn't figure out the twist and wanted to go as close as the examples

Comment: @himura, I understand.  However the correct way is to avoid using select/activate.  Only once or twice have I ever found a legitimate reason to use select/activate. Learning the correct way now will save you tons of headaches, just take a look at the second section of Barranka's code if you haven't already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a sample code, but it may help you get on your way:

```
Public Sub testIt()
    Workbooks("Workbook2").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

I am assuming that you can open the book (called `Workbook2` in the example).

---

I think (but I'm not sure) you can squash all this in a single line of code:

```
    Workbooks("Workbook2").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3").EntireRow.Insert
```

This way you won't need to activate the workbook (or sheet or cell)... Obviously, the book has to be open.

Comment: Notice that you can change `ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Select` with `ActiveSheet.Cells(2,3).Select`

Comment: + 1 for `Workbooks("Workbook2").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3").EntireRow.Insert`

Comment: Did not work for me. But assuming macro is activated from correct workbook and sheet the following worked fine in Excel 2010. 
Range(1, 1).Select